# Accuracy reduction in real time sign language GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on Sign Language to text conversion dataset. I have used Convolutional Neural Network for the model training. While training, validation accuracy is showing very good. For the same, I have created GUI using tkinter. While testing on GUI, the model accuracy is very bad and not able to detect any signs accurately. Any idea why is it happening?

[image: Model Accuracy]

[image: GUI output]

Here in GUI I am doing the sign of Alphabet A but it shows Q only. In output it shows only Q or J.

Comment: without seeing any code is difficult to guess. Is your data correctly been captured from the video and transformed into data that the CNN can process?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki which code shall I share? The one for the model or the one for prediction

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki for training it is taking the data stored in form of images from the dataset folder.

Comment: Ok, store the image you get from the GUI and compare it with the training images. Does it have the same resolution and properties?

Comment: Yes, on predicting it shows accurate results but when real-time starts it gets down

Comment: So you are using the same illumination, background, resolution than the training set? your test data must be similar to the train data

Comment: I have added some more images for the reference

Comment: don;t put images of your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246229/discussion-between-ninad-kulkarni-and-sembei-norimaki).